# Allocation memory for string

Tags: string, d

In D string is alias on immutable `char[]`. So every operation on string processing with allocation of memory. I tied to check it, but after replacing symbol in string I see the same address.

```
string str = "big";
writeln(&str);
str.replace("i","a");
writeln(&str);
```

Output:

```
> app.exe
19FE10
19FE10
```

I tried use `ptr`:

```
string str = "big";
writeln(str.ptr);
str.replace(`i`,`a`);
writeln(str.ptr);
```

And got next output:

```
42E080
42E080
```

So it's showing the same address. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a simple error in your code:

> str.replace("i","a");

`str.replace` *returns* the new string with the replacement done, it doesn't actually replace the existing variable. So try `str = str.replace("i", "a");` to see the change.

But you also made a too broadly general statement about allocations:

> So every operation on string processing with allocation of memory.

That's false, a great many operations do not require allocation of new memory. Anything that can slice the existing string will do so, avoiding needing new memory:

```
import std.string;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
        string a = "  foo  ";
        string b = a.strip();
        assert(b == "foo"); // whitespace stripped off...

        writeln(a.ptr);
        writeln(b.ptr); // but notice how close those ptrs are
        assert(b.ptr == a.ptr + 2); //  yes, b is a slice of a
}
```

`replace` will also return the original string if no replacement was actually done:

```
string a = "  foo  ";
string b = a.replace("p", "a"); // there is no p to replace
assert(a.ptr is b.ptr); // so same string returned
```

Indexing and iteration require no new allocation (of course). Believe it or not, but even appending sometimes will not allocate because there may be memory left at the end of the slice that is not yet used (though it usually will).

There's also various functions that return range objects that do the changes as you iterate through them, avoiding allocation. For example, instead of `replace(a, "f", "");`, you might do something like `filter!(ch => ch != 'f')(a);` and loop through, which doesn't allocate a new string unless you ask it to.

So it is a lot more nuanced than you might think!

Comment: what difference between `     string *str_ptr;
    str_ptr = &str;
    writeln(str_ptr);` and ` writeln(str.ptr);`

Comment: `&str` is a pointer to the ARRAY, `str.ptr` is a pointer to the CONTENTS.

Answer (score 0):

In D all arrays are a length + a pointer to the start of the array values. These are usually stored on the stack which just so happens to be RAM.

When you go take an address of a variable (which is in a function body) what you really are doing is getting a pointer to the stack.

To get the address of an array values use `.ptr`.
So replace `&str` with `str.ptr` and you will get  the correct output.

Comment: I have tested it and it's show the same address. Se my last topic editing.